# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) when get data from Directions API using axios with Nuxt js

Tags: ajax, cors, axios, nuxt.js, vue2-google-maps

In my Nuxt project, I use vue2-google-maps library to create map and axios to get data from Map API.
I want to get distance between 2 location in google map, so i use Directions API: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood&key=API_KEY. 
When I use it with Insomnia, I retrieved data normally, like below picture:

[image]

But when i use it with nuxt using axios, I get some error like:

[image]

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood&key=API_KEY with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

But if i use Geocoding API with nuxt, it work normally
I tried adding header Access-Control-Allow-Origin=* but still get errors.
I don’t know why i get these errors.
My code:

```js
axios
  .get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood&key=API_KEY')
  .then(res => {
      console.log("Res: ");
      console.log(res)
   })
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Please help me.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `nuxt.config.js`, you have to put credentials: false to allow CORS wildcard.

Modify config as follows.

```
axios: {
   baseURL: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api',
   proxyHeaders: false,
   credentials: false
}
```

[image]

CORS header is not present in the response from Google Maps because it is designed to be utilized for server-side applications. For client-side (Browser), you need to make use of [Official Maps library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions). (Shown in the above image).

Reference: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#credentials

Comment: I tried your guide like:
in my nuxt.config.js:
 modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],
  axios: {
    baseURL: ' https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api ',
    proxyHeaders: false,
    credentials: false
  },
But i still got these errors

Comment: @NguyễnVănĐại See google maps API you are using is a Server side API. That's why `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not present.You need to make use of [client-side JS library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

Comment: Do mark the answer verified if this solves your problem. Cheers

Comment: But why i use Geocoding API with axios in Nuxt, it work normally @Bharathvaj Ganesan

Comment: It looks like this API is been hit only on the client side i.e browser. It should have been hit on the server side before serving to the browser.

Comment: Thank you. I use DirectionsService, and that fixed my problem.
This is the link for my question: https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/issues/174